Flutter: How to use "ffmpeg_kit_flutter" to merge videos?
i am using "ffmpeg_kit_flutter" to merge two videos with code

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/abstract_session.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/return_code.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:wechat_assets_picker/wechat_assets_picker.dart';

import '/features/merge_videos/cubit/merge_videos_state.dart';

class MergeVideosCubit extends Cubit<MergeVideosState> {
  MergeVideosCubit(this.originalFile) : super(InitialMergeVideos());
  final File? originalFile;

  Future<void> selectVideo(BuildContext context) async {
    final List<AssetEntity>? videos = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(
      context,
      pickerConfig: const AssetPickerConfig(requestType: RequestType.video),
    );

    if (videos != null && videos.isNotEmpty) {
      for (AssetEntity asset in videos) {
        File? videoFile = await asset.file;
        if (videoFile != null) {
          print('Selected Asset Path: ${videoFile.path}');
          mergeVideos(originalFile!.path, videoFile.path);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> mergeVideos(String inputPath1, String inputPath2) async {
    final String outputPath = "/storage/emulated/0/merged_video_${now()}.mp4";
    // final String command =
    //     '-i $inputPath1 -i $inputPath2 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -y $outputPath';
    final String command =
        '-i $inputPath1 -i $inputPath2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map "[outv]" -y $outputPath';
    print("FFmpeg process starting with command: $command");
    print(command);
    print("LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING MERGE");
    emit(LoadMergeVideos());
    await FFmpegKit.execute(command).then((value) async {
      await value.getDuration();
      var id = await value.getSessionId();

      print(value);
      print(id);
      print(await value.getDuration());
    });
    await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command, (session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      await session.getSessionId();
      print(await session.getSessionId());

      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        print("SUCCESS: Video merged successfully at $outputPath");
        print("SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS MERGE");
        emit(SuccessMergeVideos());

      } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
        print("CANCELLED: Video merging was cancelled.");
        print("CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL MERGE");
        emit(CancelMergeVideos());

      } else {
        print("ERROR: Failed to merge videos.");
        print("ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR MERGE");
        emit(ErrorMergeVideos());

        final failLog = await session.getFailStackTrace();

        print("FFmpeg Failure Log: $failLog");
      }
    });
  }

  String now() {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    return "${now.year}${now.month}${now.day}_${now.hour}${now.minute}${now.second}";
  }
}

The console when i run the code

D/EGL_emulation(23858): app_time_stats: avg=2379.66ms min=5.87ms max=23160.09ms count=10
I/PhotoManager(23858): uri: content://media/external/file
I/PhotoManager(23858): projection: _display_name, _data, _id, title, bucket_id, bucket_display_name, width, height, orientation, date_added, date_modified, mime_type, datetaken, duration, media_type, relative_path
I/PhotoManager(23858): selection: _id = ?
I/PhotoManager(23858): selectionArgs: 1000000039
I/PhotoManager(23858): sortOrder: null
I/PhotoManager(23858): sql: _id = 1000000039
I/PhotoManager(23858): cursor count: 1
I/flutter (23858): Selected Asset Path: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115116.mp4
I/flutter (23858): FFmpeg process starting with command: -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115128.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115116.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map "[outv]" -y /storage/emulated/0/merged_video_2024513_122719.mp4
I/flutter (23858): -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115128.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115116.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map "[outv]" -y /storage/emulated/0/merged_video_2024513_122719.mp4
I/flutter (23858): LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING MERGE
I/flutter (23858): Instance of 'FFmpegSession'
I/flutter (23858): 1
I/flutter (23858): 246
I/flutter (23858): 2
I/flutter (23858): ERROR: Failed to merge videos.
I/flutter (23858): ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR MERGE
D/EGL_emulation(23858): app_time_stats: avg=87.27ms min=4.92ms max=319.92ms count=13
I/flutter (23858): FFmpeg Failure Log: null

In "mergeVideos" function the "returnCode" it return value "1" when i look in the package code
getState() async {
    try {
      return _platform
          .abstractSessionGetState(this.getSessionId())
          .then((state) {
        switch (state) {
          case 0:
            return SessionState.created;
          case 1:
            return SessionState.running;
          case 2:
            return SessionState.failed;
          case 3:
          default:
            return SessionState.completed;
        }
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e, stack) {
      print("Plugin getState error: ${e.message}");
      return Future.error("getState failed.", stack);
    }
}

Which mean its keep running but in my code it does not wait until complete merging
how can i fix that??!
but i think my problem is in command(concat)

-i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115128.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20240512_115116.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map "[outv]" -y /storage/emulated/0/merged_video_2024513_122719.mp4

(This is my command when i run the code)??

the problem was in command(concat) (the outputPath (the location where to save the merge video)) it was not allow to save on storage (the path must be exist on storage)
so i fix it by using "path_provider" package which allow me to save

Future<void> mergeVideos(String inputPath1, String inputPath2) async {

    final Directory appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final outputPath = '${appDocumentsDir.path}/merged_video_${now()}.mp4';

    final String command =
        '-i $inputPath1 -i $inputPath2 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -y $outputPath';

    print("FFmpeg process starting with command: $command");

    print(command);

    emit(LoadMergeVideos());
    print("LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING LOADING MERGE");

    await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command, (session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      final log = await session.getAllLogsAsString();
      final failStackTrace = await session.getFailStackTrace();

      print("FFmpeg Log: $log");
      print(failStackTrace);

      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        print("SUCCESS: Video merged successfully at $outputPath");
        print("SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS SUCCESS MERGE");
        emit(SuccessMergeVideos());
      } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
        print("CANCELLED: Video merging was cancelled.");
        emit(CancelMergeVideos());
        print("CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL CANCEL MERGE");
      } else {
        print("ERROR: Failed to merge videos.");
        print("ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR MERGE");
        emit(ErrorMergeVideos());

        final failLog = await session.getFailStackTrace();
        print("FFmpeg Failure Log: $failLog");
      }
    },(log) {
      print(log.getSessionId());
      print(log.getMessage());
    }, (statistics) {
      statistics1 = statistics;
      print(statistics);
    },);
  }


